# Run equals and isnull statement in one query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this query

```
 DECLARE @LastDesignKey INT = (SELECT TOP 1 
                                   MAX([DesignKey])
                               FROM [Design] AS [D]
                               INNER JOIN [DesignGroup] AS [DG] ON [D].[DesignGroupId] = [DG].[DesignGroupId]
                               INNER JOIN [DesignType] AS [DT] ON [D].[DesignTypeGuid] = [DT].[DesignTypeGuid]
                               WHERE [D].[ParentDesignKey] = @ParentDesignKey 
                                 AND [DT].[Abbreviation] = @DesignTypeName
                                 AND [DG].[ProjectKey] = @ProjectKey)
```

In order to test it I added static variables:

```
 DECLARE @ParentDesignKey INT = NULL, 
         @DesignTypeName VARCHAR(266) = 'BD',
         @ProjectKey INT = 4395


DECLARE @LastDesignKey INT = (SELECT TOP 1 MAX([DesignKey])
                              FROM [Design] AS [D]
                              INNER JOIN [DesignGroup] AS [DG] ON [D].[DesignGroupId] = [DG].[DesignGroupId]
                              INNER JOIN [DesignType] AS [DT] ON [D].[DesignTypeGuid] = [DT].[DesignTypeGuid]
                              WHERE [D].[ParentDesignKey] = @ParentDesignKey
                                AND [DT].[Abbreviation] = @DesignTypeName
                                AND [DG].[ProjectKey] = @ProjectKey)

  SELECT @LastDesignKey
```

As you can see in my where clause I have `WHERE [D].[ParentDesignKey] = @ParentDesignKey`, but `@ParentDesignKey` variable sometimes
  can be null, so my resut there is wrong because to check null you can't use:

WRONG use:

```
 WHERE [D].[ParentDesignKey] = NULL
```

CORRECT use

```
  WHERE [D].[ParentDesignKey] IS NULL
```

What can I do in my query to support IS NULL and = ? Regards

Comment: `WHERE ([D].[ParentDesignKey] = @ParentDesignKey or @ParentDesignKey is null)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add explicit logic:

```
WHERE ([D].[ParentDesignKey] = @ParentDesignKey OR [D].[ParentDesignKey] IS NULL AND @ParentDesignKey IS NULL) OR
      ([DT].[Abbreviation] = @DesignTypeName OR [DT].[Abbreviation] IS NULL AND @DesignTypeName IS NULL) OR
      ([DG].[ProjectKey] = @ProjectKey OR [DG].[ProjectKey] IS NULL AND @ProjectKey IS NULL)
```

Note that if you are depending on indexes for performance, this will kill performance.  If that is the case, you probably want to use a non-`NULL` default value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `OR ... IS NULL` condition:

```
WHERE ([D].[ParentDesignKey] = @ParentDesignKey OR  @ParentDesignKey IS NULL)
  AND ([DT].[Abbreviation] = @DesignTypeName OR @DesignTypeName IS NULL)
  AND ([DG].[ProjectKey] = @ProjectKey OR @ProjectKey IS NULL)
OPTION(RECOMPILE) -- to force using actual values instead of parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just add or to nullable variable

```
   DECLARE @ParentDesignKey INT = NULL, 
             @DesignTypeName VARCHAR(266) = 'BD',
             @ProjectKey INT = 4395


    DECLARE @LastDesignKey INT = (SELECT TOP 1 MAX([DesignKey])
                                  FROM [Design] AS [D]
                                  INNER JOIN [DesignGroup] AS [DG] ON [D].[DesignGroupId] = [DG].[DesignGroupId]
                                  INNER JOIN [DesignType] AS [DT] ON [D].[DesignTypeGuid] = [DT].[DesignTypeGuid]
                                  WHERE (      [D].[ParentDesignKey] = @ParentDesignKey 
                                          or ( [D].[ParentDesignKey] is null  and @ParentDesignKey is null )
                                         )
                                    AND [DT].[Abbreviation] = @DesignTypeName
                                    AND [DG].[ProjectKey] = @ProjectKey)

      SELECT @LastDesignKey
```